# How do I echo this array in a for loop?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, dynamic-arrays

I have some arrays that have each 4 values in them, named:

```
$myarray_row0
$myarray_row1
$myarray_row2
```

So normally I can use this echo statement to get at the values in the first array:

```
echo 'My value is '.$myarray_row0[0];   // This works fine
```

But I want to use a FOR LOOP to iterate through them and I'm getting stuck because I want to use something like:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=10; $i++)
{
 echo 'My value is '.$myarray_row[$i][[$i]];
 echo 'My value is '.$myarray_row[$i][$i+1]];
 echo 'My value is '.$myarray_row[$i][[$i+2]];
 echo 'My value is '.$myarray_row[$i][[$i+3]];
}
```

I'm not using the correct syntax for the $i's and the brackets needed... I'm TRYING (but failing) to get the echo to spit out the arrays contents, such as:

```
$myarray_row0[0]
$myarray_row0[1]
$myarray_row0[2]
$myarray_row0[3]
etc
```

Note that it's not truly a multidimensional array, it's one dimensional, but it almost LOOKS like it is multi-dimensional since the array names have 'row0', 'row1', 'row2', etc in them.

Anyone know the syntax for getting a variable like $myarray_row0[1]  to be echo'ed using the $i's that are available inside the for loop?

THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to use a variable variable name. (its been a while since ive used php so might be wrong)

```
for ($i=0;$i<10l$i++) {
    echo 'My variable name is '.${'myarray_row'.$id}[$i+0];
    echo 'My variable name is '.${'myarray_row'.$id}[$i+1];
    echo 'My variable name is '.${'myarray_row'.$id}[$i+2];
    echo 'My variable name is '.${'myarray_row'.$id}[$i+3];
}
```

However, its generally a good idea to not use them at all. making a multi-dimensional array instead would be much better for your case.

Question: if your `$myarray_rowN` has 4 elements why does your example have `$i+X` in the index?

surely it will go out of bounds after the first iteration :/ (1+1 OK, 1+2 OK, 1+3 OK 1+4 !OK etc)

possibly something like this might be better? <strike>(could be javascript though)</strike>

```
$index = 0;
$rows = array();
while (isset(${'myarray_row'.$i})) {
    array_push($rows, ${'myarray_row'.$i});
}
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo 'My variable name is '.$row[0]."\r\n";
    echo 'My variable name is '.$row[1]."\r\n";
    echo 'My variable name is '.$row[2]."\r\n";
    echo 'My variable name is '.$row[3]."\r\n";
}
```

Comment: Nick - thanks!  You bring up a GREAT question which was the out of bounds problem with $i + x    I didn't think about it but I could nest a for loop that runs 4 iterations INSIDE of the main loop which runs 13 times (it's creating Table rows).    OK I tried it.. it works!!   I have 2 nested for loops... one runs 13 times using $j and the inner loop runs 4 times using $i:    **echo 'some html here '.${'myarrray_row'.$j}[$i].'</td></tr>';**   MANY THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use a variable variable.  See the docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Something like this should work:

```
for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
  $var = 'myarray_row'.$i;
  echo 'My variable name is ' . $$var[$i+0];
  ...
}
```

Comment: Ah that looks like a simple way.. :-)   Thank you Hibiscus, I am a newb so I didn't know about $$ variable variables, but I'm reading your link. Thanks! helpful.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this:

```
foreach($myarray_row0 as $key => $value){
echo 'The ' . $key . ' value of this array is: ' . $value;
}
```

The above will iterate through all values in `$myarray_row0` and echo the current value

Comment: Fantastic!! This works too. THANKS Evan.. I'm learning :) thanks to you helpful folks. Cheers.  Didn't have a clue about this method.

Comment: Evan - the first answer was the one that had the tidbit I really needed re syntax on $myarray_row0[0] etc.. so I had to mark that one but your tip is AWESOME and I wish I could mark it also for value!

Comment: @TimDonahue hey, not to worry! Glad you got it all settled. Good luck.